# How to close any open InfoWindow's using jquery-ui-map (Google Map v3 plugin for jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3, jquery-ui-map

The user has markers loaded depending on where they select their location. The markers are cleared when a new location is chosen. If I have an InfoWindow open when I clear the markers, it stays open even though the marker goes away. I want any open InfoWindow to close when the data is refreshed.

**My implementation details:**

I am using [jquery-ui-map](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/) to enhance my Google Maps implementation with jQuery.

I attach a click event when creating the markers with the following code (FYI: I took out all the specific details and replaced them with generic ones).

```
$('#map-canvas').gmap('addMarker', {
    'position' : new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
    'title' : myTitle,
    'icon' : myImage,
    'shadow' : myShadowImage
}).click(function() {
    $('#map-canvas').gmap('openInfoWindow', {
        'content' : displayContent(myObject)
    }, this);
});
```

The option `openInfoWindow` does not return anything, so storing the InfoWindow object in an array to close it later does not look like a viable option.

Does anyone know how to achieve this using the jquery-ui-map library? I don't see a closeInfoWindow listed in the API documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jquery-ui-map v.beta

```
var theInfoWindowObject = $('#map_canvas').gmap('get', 'iw');
theInfoWindowObject.close();
```

jquery-ui-map v rc 1

```
$('#map_canvas').gmap('closeInfoWindow');
```

Comment: so what if I want to call this everytime the map receives a click?

Comment: how to close the single one infoWindow?

Comment: this `$('#map_canvas').gmap('get','iw', arrMarkers[marker.id].info_window).close()` closes all :(